# Bash command not found due to stray garbage characters

Tags: bash, readline, line-editor

What is the cause of this behavior?

```
$ cd ../
$ bash: $'\210\210cd': command not found
```

This happens sometimes (rarely) when I enter a command, there is no visible character preceding the `cd`, still it appears there are.

Am I simply somehow hitting keys on the keyboard I'm not aware of? Or is there a different cause of this?

GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: No - that's a bug in `bash`. Those `\210\210` characters you see really are *stray garbage*. There's a memory leak in `bash` somewhere *(maybe in its `$IFS` breakup routines, or - given the conditions you name - more likely in its command search routines)* in which it winds up leaking internally delimited strings to output.  If you watch what `bash` does in `ltrace` you'll see it tends to `strcmp()` just about every command you enter against a `\201...\210` delimiter string - looking for the tail of a *word*. Possibly your terminal is feeding it nulls and it doesn't know how to cope.

Comment: Indeed there's a chance that this is a bug in bash itself. Can you reproduce this without a `.bashrc` (run `bash --norc`)? Can you reproduce this without a `.inputrc`? What is the content of your `.inputrc`? What character encoding do you use (output of `locale | grep LC_CTYPE`? If you encounter the bug, and press `Up` and `Enter` to run the command again, do you get the same message?

Comment: Sometimes when I hit `<esc>` and then a key, I get funny invisible characters, perhaps you did that.

Comment: Gilles: I have no way of deterministically reproducing the issue. Hence I would need to simply run a terminal like that and wait. Sometimes I can use a terminal for a day without producing the issue. My .inputrc is empty and I use en_US. If I press up and enter I do indeed get the same error/message. Also when I press up, I noticed that there is now a difference -- it eats up a character to the left, i.e. "$ cd" becomes "$cd".